# R principal component analysis interpreting the princomp() and eigen() functions for a non-square matrix

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to learn about and implement principal component analysis and study in particular how it relates to eigenvectors and eigenvalues and other things from linear algebra. Cross Validated has been helpful but I do have questions I haven't seen an answer for so far.

I've read online that eigenvalues and eigenvalues are for square matrices and singular value decomposition is like an extension of that for non-square matrices. Here is what I find on Google when I search the question:

*Note. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are only for square matrices. Eigenvectors are by definition nonzero. Eigenvalues may be equal to zero.*

But if I take, for example, a selection from the `mtcars` dataset, by choosing only the first six rows but keeping all the observations, and then ask about the dimensions of this new dataset, I see that I have a `m x n` matrix that is a `32 x 6` matrix.

```
mtcars_selection <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(mpg:wt)

nrow(mtcars_selection) # 32
length(mtcars_selection) # 6
```

Now turning to principal component analysis, when I run these lines of code:

```
prcomp_attempt = stats::prcomp(mtcars_selection, scale = FALSE)
summary(prcomp_attempt)
```

I get the following as part of the output.

```
                           PC1      PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5    PC6
Standard deviation     136.5265 38.11828 3.04062 0.67678 0.36761 0.3076
Proportion of Variance   0.9272  0.07228 0.00046 0.00002 0.00001 0.0000
Cumulative Proportion    0.9272  0.99951 0.99997 0.99999 1.00000 1.0000
```

Similarly, when I change `prcomp()` to `princomp()` I get a similar output.

```
princomp_attempt = stats::princomp(mtcars_selection, scale = FALSE)
summary(princomp_attempt)

                            Comp.1      Comp.2       Comp.3        Comp.4         Comp.5         Comp.6
Standard deviation     134.3763479 37.51795949 2.9927313123 0.66612093849 0.361823645756 0.302784248968
Proportion of Variance   0.9272258  0.07228002 0.0004599126 0.00002278484 0.000006722546 0.000004707674
Cumulative Proportion    0.9272258  0.99950587 0.9999657849 0.99998856978 0.999995292326 1.000000000000
```

From `?prcomp()` I see that the computation is done using singular value decomposition.

*The calculation is done by a singular value decomposition of the (centered and possibly scaled) data matrix, not by using eigen on the covariance matrix. This is generally the preferred method for numerical accuracy.*

And from `?princomp()` I see:

*The calculation is done using eigen on the correlation or covariance matrix, as determined by cor. This is done for compatibility with the S-PLUS result.*

But doesn't this all mean that one of the code chunks above should work and one of them should not work? In particular, how did `princomp()` work if the matrix that went into the `princomp()` function is a non-square matrix?

Now when I take a look at the `eigen()` function on the covariance matrix, which is non-square, I get an output that looks like it only printed the first six rows.

```
eigen(cov(mtcars_selection))
```

I see in this particular output

```
             [,1]         [,2]        [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
[1,]  0.038119604 -0.009201962  0.99282561 -0.057597550  0.094821246  0.021236444
[2,] -0.012035481  0.003373585 -0.06561936 -0.965667568  0.050583003  0.245897079
[3,] -0.899622021 -0.435427435  0.03153733  0.006753430 -0.006294596 -0.001825989
[4,] -0.434782990  0.900148911  0.02503332  0.006406853  0.004534789 -0.002722171
[5,]  0.002660336  0.003898813  0.03993024  0.187172744 -0.494914521  0.847590278
[6,] -0.006239859 -0.004861028 -0.08231475  0.170435844  0.862235306  0.469748461
```

In the `eigen()` and the `princomp()` functions, is the the data being conformed to a square matrix by slicing off the rows that are greater in number than the columns, so `m = n`?

Comment: It means that you can obtain the principal components (or more precisely the loadings and then the principal components) with two "algorithms": either you apply an eigen decomposition on the (square) covariance (or correlation) matrix, or you apply a singular value decomposition on the (rectangular) centered (and standardized, if needed) data.

Comment: Also: it is a really bad idea to teach yourself a new technique by reading the help files of the functions that perform these techniques

Comment: Thanks for the comment under the post. On the one hand, I totally missed the obvious fact that the correlation matrix and the covariance are square... But also, I didn't realize that the svd was performed on the original data, centered and maybe standardized - I thought the svd was also done on the correlation or covariance matrix. So you cleared up two things for me here